# C program ends after outb, no errors thrown

Tags: c, io

I am writing a simple program to read the Realtime Clock in C. I have set my permissions to allow the program to access the proper register with ioperm(), and run with "sudo" to allow permissions to be changed. When I call outb() it may or may not execute properly, but none of the subsequent code executes.

```
int error = ioperm(0x70, 4, 1);
printf("%d\n", error);

outb(0x70, 0x04);            //stops here
char past[30] = "beyond outb";
printf("%s\n", past);

unsigned int hour = inb(0x71);
```

**note: I'm aware that this will not produce the desired output regardless. I just need to get to inb() and I know what I need to do from there.

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger to see what's happening at that line?

Comment: Yes, I compiled using the -ggdb tag in gcc, but it only said that some things had multiple definitions, main being the odd one because It only has one definition in my program.

Comment: The compiler isn't the debugger.

Comment: You should pay heed to compiler and/or linker errors/warnings. Pleas post a [mcve]. As given, it is not clear what is your actual problem.

Comment: Ok, I ran it through gdb with a break point at outb, and it output

-1

Program received signal SIGSEGV Segmentation Fault
0x0000000000400699 in main()

Comment: Are you sure `ioperm()` succeeded?